# How to convert a lot of columns from long type to integer type in PySpark?

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a dataframe with around 50+ columns all in the "long" format. I would like to batch process 40 of them to be converted to "integer" format.

Do I have to keep repeating below?

```
df = df \
    .withColumn('colA', col('colA').cast(IntegerType())) \
    .withColumn('colB', col('colB').cast(IntegerType())) \
    .withColumn('colC', col('colC').cast(IntegerType())) \
 ....
```

Above looks pretty manual to me. I am new to PySpark, so not sure if I can put all columns into a list, and only use `cast` once (like what I would have done in Python).

Greatly appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2):

Use something like below (if you want to cast all your columns at once) -

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

df.select(*(col(c).cast("integer").alias(c) for c in df.columns))
```

Answer (score 2):

In this case I would probably use [reduce](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html), because in python 3, it has been turned into a c wrapper and it quite fast. Warning- It may be more computationally expensive where you are selectively casting columns because it will scan through the entire dataframe before casting specified columns. Can explore this by running `.explain()`

```
from functools import reduce 
out = reduce(
    lambda df, c: df.withColumn(c, df[c].cast('integer')), 
    df.columns,
    df
)#.explain()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

my_cols = ['col1', 'col2']

for c in my_cols:
  df = df.withColumn(c, F.col(c).cast('Integer'))
```